# Html Agility Pack how to get dynamically generated content after page loads

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to get information from "https://www.sideshow.com/collectibles?manufacturer=Hot+Toys"
specifically Div c-ProductList row ss-targeted but no information seems to be retrieved, any clues

```
var test = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='c-ProductList row ss-targeted']");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content you want to get is generated after the page loads, using Javascript and Ajax. HAP cannot get it unless it runs a browser in background and execute the scripts on the page.

**.Net Core 2.0**

Pre-requisites: you need Chrome web browser installed in your PC.

1. Create a console application
2. Install Nuget packages
   `Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack`
   `Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver`
   `Install-Package Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver`
3. Replace `Main` method by the following

**Code:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "https://www.sideshow.com/collectibles?manufacturer=Hot+Toys";
        var browser = new ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        browser.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

        var results = browser.FindElementByClassName("ss-results");
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(results.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));

        // Show results
        var list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='c-ProductList row ss-targeted']");
        foreach (var title in list.SelectNodes(".//h2[@class='c-ProductListItem__title ng-binding']"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(title.InnerText);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**.Net 4.6**

1. Create a console application
2. Install Nuget package `Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack`
3. In **Solution Explorer** add reference to `System.Windows.Form`
4. Add `using` statements as required
5. Replace `Main` method by the following

**Code:**

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "https://www.sideshow.com/collectibles?manufacturer=Hot+Toys";

    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    web.BrowserTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

    var doc = web.LoadFromBrowser(url, o =>
    {
        var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)o;

        // Wait until the list shows up
        return webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml.Contains("c-ProductList");
    });

    // Show results
    var list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='c-ProductList row ss-targeted']");
    foreach (var title in list.SelectNodes(".//h2[@class='c-ProductListItem__title ng-binding']"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(title.InnerText);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Displays a list starting with:

> Iron Man Mark L
>
> John Wick
>
> The Punisher War Machine Armor
>
> Wonder Woman Deluxe Version

Comment: i am using .Net Core 2.0 :(

Comment: @DeanBeckerton According to [documentation](https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/46981666/htmlagilitypack-loadfrombrowser-method-not-found), there's no `WebBrowser` class in Core. The question was not tagged as Core but I have updated my answer for supporting it by following the suggestions in HAP website.

Comment: @derloopkat the solution looks promising and I would like to use it in my website written using .net 4.6, ASP.net. Could you please update the answer for this environment. I tried to implement the solution here but I am getting errors such as "HtmlWeb does not contain a definition for "LoadFromWeb".

Comment: @giparekh, the name of the method is `LoadFromBrowser()`. I have tested in 4.6 and it works. Package version is `<package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.11.18" targetFramework="net46" />`. May be you have older version or method name is mispelled.

Comment: Perfect. I was using older version. Newer version has resolved the issue. but now started getting new exception as "ThreadStateException: ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment." at LoadFromBrowser(). Actually, I am going to scrap data from a website https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/us-treasury/10-year-us-treasury-note.html  and the element here is "td" with the id A"quotesFuturesProductTable1_ZNU0_last" but doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode returns null.

Comment: I have resolved the STA exception by using AspCompat="true" in a page directive. Thanks for the solution @derloopkat. This is very helpful.